# implement Numerical Edit Text in Android

Tags: android-widget, android-edittext, android

I am trying to implement getting contents of edit text as a number as exemplified in iOS. 
The intention is for the user to enter only numerical values.

I am wondering if there is a similar implementation in Android. Can this be done??

I would appreciate some excellent advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `android:numeric` for this like:

```
<EditText android:text="435.569"
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numeric="integer|decimal" />
```

to do this dynamically just try something like :`EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

Good luck
Arkde

Comment: Arkde, thanks a load, I am thinking of implementing it in code..Could you please advise??

Answer (score 0):

The `EditText`-widget has the [`inputType`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType), which can be used to determine what type of input the user should make.

There is also the corresponding method [`setRawInputType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29) to set it programmily.

Comment: Lukas, thank you..Could you please provide me an example I can reference?

Comment: If you use XML for your Layout-Definition, simply add the attribute. If you use Java, use the above method on your `EditText`-object.